# Can not setup open directory due to host name

Tags: server.app, open-directory

In activing Open Directory on a new install of OS X, I am able to put in a diradmin name/password, and they I get the following dialog:

> This computer's host name is invalid.
>
> The host name does not resolve to any configured address of this computer.  Please ensure the host name is correct.

I have checked

```
scutil --get ComputerName
scutil --get HostName
scutil --get LocalHostName
```

Each has returned what I expected (the machine name...the domain we are on, and the LocalHostName which matches the ComputerName.

My goal is to restore a backup of a live OD server to this one along with passwords.

Answer (score 1):

That "what I expected" part seems wrong.

```
LocalHostName + <your domain name> should equal HostName
```

so, if HostName is myserver and your domain is sample.com than
LocalHostName should be "myserver" and HostName should be 
"myserver.sample.com".

In a terminal,

```
dig `scutil --get HostName`
```

should return the IP adress of your server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps:

```
sudo vi /private/etc/hosts
```

add

```
[IP]            [hostname]
```

e.g:

```
192.168.2.100   myhostname.local
```

And try again !

Comment: myhostname.local is no proper host name in the hosts file in an OD environment! The .local tld is reserved for Bonjour/zeroconf. A proper entry would be myhostname.sld.tld. tld≠local (and some other). But even then it's a dirty trick because a dns-server set up properly is required to get a working  OD.